# Bootstrap tab throws data[option] is not a function error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a few bootstrap tabs, each one containing a form, and I put a Cancel button with class of `cancel_preset` and I have this function for it:

```
$(".cancel_preset").on("click", function(){
    var _tab=$(this).closest(".tab-pane").attr("id"); //prints the correct id for every tab
    $("a[href='#"+_tab+"']").tab('hide');
});
```

but it gives me this error `line: tab.js:124 Uncaught TypeError: data[option] is not a function`

Html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <h4>Select preset:</h4>
    <li><a href="#create_preset_intro" class="preset_tab_toggle" data-toggle="tab" data-title="Intro preset (new)" id="preset_intro">Intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="#create_preset_normal" class="preset_tab_toggle" data-toggle="tab" data-title="Normal preset (new)" id="preset_normal">Normal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#create_preset_proprietary" class="preset_tab_toggle" data-toggle="tab" data-title="Proprietary preset (new)" id="preset_proprietary">Proprietary</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="preset-content">
    <div class="tab-pane preset-containor" id="create_preset_intro">
        <form class="preset" id="f_preset_intro">
            <!-- some form inputs -->
            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <div class="pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancel_preset">Cancel</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit_preset">Create</button>
            </div>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane preset-containor" id="create_preset_normal">
        <form class="preset" id="f_preset_normal">
            <!-- some form inputs -->
            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <div class="pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancel_preset">Cancel</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit_preset">Create</button>
            </div>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane preset-containor" id="create_preset_proprietary">
        <form class="preset" id="f_preset_proprietary">
            <!-- some form inputs -->
            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <div class="pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancel_preset">Cancel</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit_preset">Create</button>
            </div>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

From what I red on other questions on this topic, most of them said that scrips are incompatible
These are my scripts includes (bootstrap.js is included by laravel):

```
    <script src="/test2/public/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/less.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/alert.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/button.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/modal.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/tab.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/popover.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/affix.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/transition.js"></script>
    <script src="/test2/public/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you please provide your html code?

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman check my edit

Comment: try the  answer which i provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
using jQuery

```
$(".cancel_preset").on("click", function(){
    var _tab=$(this).closest(".tab-pane").attr("id");
    $("a[href='#"+_tab+"']").parent().hide();
    $("#"+_tab).hide();
});
```

Comment: ok, I tried something similar, but `$("a[href='#"+_tab+"']").hide();` hides the link to the tab, not the tab itself, so it should be `$("#"+_tab).hide();` and then the `$("a[href='#"+_tab+"']").parent().removeClass('active');` is needed too. BUT you can't then click again on that tab

Comment: So that's why I'd like the twitter bootstrap tab function to work

Comment: but your reference, you no mention  bootstrap. may be you miss.

Comment: but the tabs work properly, and I'm using laravel which includes bootstrap, I'll try to include it manually, plus the `show.bs.tab` event works

Comment: I tried including bootstra.js manually, but I still get the same error

Comment: ok, so there is no such thing as `.tab('hide')` apparently only `.tab('show')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142490/discussion-between-ashiquzzaman-and-cr1xus).